# Exibindo formulário através do Select com Jquery!

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql

Tenho um campo select para o usuário escolher qual formulário deseja cadastrar os dados! ( 2 formulários a serem exibidos). Ao selecionar a primeira opção no select, estou utilizando Jquery hide() e show() para exibir os formulários escolhidos.

Os formulários possuem um campo select que retorna dados do BD para o usuário escolher a opção!

Sendo que os dois formulários são os mesmos, gostaria de retornar duas consultas do banco de dados no mesmo formulário quando o usuário mudar a opção no select! Obs: estou desenvolvendo este formulário em PHP MySQL!

Obs: Consegui retornar apenas uma consulta!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function validar(){
var idDepartamento   = formInsere.idDepartamento.value;
var descRamal        = formInsere.descRamal.value;
var numRamal         = formInsere.numRamal.value;

if(idDepartamento == ""){
alert('Selecione o nome Terminal!');
formInsere.idDepartamento.focus();
return false;    
}    

if(descRamal == ""){
alert('Informe a descri\u00e7\u00e3o do ramal!');   
formInsere.descRamal.focus();
return false;
}

if(numRamal == ""){
alert('Informe o n\u00famero do ramal!');
formInsere.numRamal.focus();
return false;
}

}//fim function//

//selecione input busca escala(data / periodo)//
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#formInTerminal').hide();    
$('#byData').hide();
$('#mySelect').change(function() {
$('#formInTerminal').hide();

    if($('#mySelect').val() == 'Form 1'){
       $('#formInTerminal').show();
    }//fim formInTerminal//    

    if($('#mySelect').val() == 'Form 2') {
       $('#formInTerminal').show();
    } else {
        //$('#formInTerminal').hide();
    }//fim if//

  });  
});//fim selecione input// 
</script>



    <?php

    $strSql = "SELECT * FROM TB_Departamento WHERE idDepartamento BETWEEN 41 AND 45 ORDER BY descricao;";
    //echo $strSql; // exit; 


    $resultadoQuery = $conexaoBD->query($strSql);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($resultadoQuery) > 0){

?>

<div class="w3-half w3-container w3-padding w3-text-gray">

    <select id="mySelect" style="width:200px" method="GET">
        <option value="opcao">Selecione</option>
        <option>Formulario 1</option>
        <option>Formulario 2</option>
    </select> <br><br>

    <form id="formInTerminal" name="formInsere" action="formInsere.php" method="POST">
        <label>&nbsp;Descricao</label>
            <select name="idDepartamento"  maxlength="80" style="width:200px">
                <option value="">Selecione</option>
                <?php while ($registro = $resultadoQuery->fetch_assoc()){?>
                <option value="<?= $registro['idDepartamento']?>"><?= $strNome = utf8_decode($registro["descricao"])?></option>
            <?php }//fim while//
                    }//fim if num_rows//

                ?>
            </select>
                <br><br>
                    <label>&nbsp;Descricao</label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="descRamal"  required="true" style="width:200px">
                    <br><br>
                <label>Descricao</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="numRamal" maxlength="4" style="width:200px">       
            <br><br>
         <!--<input type="submit" onclick="return validar()" value="salvar">-->
         <button class="w3-button" style="background:#b8cad4;" type="submit" onclick="return validar()">Salvar</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado @André Lins! Sou novato aqui!

Answer (score 0):

você pode verificar pelo valor do select

primeiro você deverá colocar um valor nos options

```
<option value="1">Formulario 1</option>
<option value="2">Formulario 2</option>
```

logo após verificar pelo código escolhido

```
valor = $('#mySelect').val()
if (valor == 1){
    $("#select1").show();
    $("#select2").hide();
}else if (valor == 2){
    $("#select1").hide();
    $("#select2").show();
}
```

coloque isso em uma função e ative com o evento change no select

faça as consultas e retorne os resultados diferentes nos selects diferentes, assim você conseguirá utilizar de maneira simples, cada select com suas opções apenas sendo escondidos

Comment: Ok! eu fiz isso e deu certo! a minha dúvida é como fazer o código em php quando selecionar o  formulário 2 e o input do formulário echoar as informações que vem do banco de dados! No formulário 1, eu consigo trazer as informações do banco, ai quando eu mudo lá no select para o formulário 2, vem as mesmas informações do select do formulário 1...

Comment: coloca dois selects, cada um trazendo as informações desejadas, ou seja, dois selects cada um com as opções trazidas do banco diferentes, depois só controla a exibição